# selectionChange does not emit for default option in mat-select - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to trigger a callback (or emit event) when `mat-select` is initialised with default value. Please see below template -

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [(value)]="selectedSearchView"  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let view of searchViews; let i=index" [value]="view">
              {{view.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there a way to call `onSelectionChange($event)` when `mat-select` is initialised?

Comment: do it in `ngAfterViewInit`, but you will need a reference to your material element (you don't have any right now)

Comment: You'd tried that, what's the issue? consoled error maybe ..

Comment: @selemmn there is no error, `selectionChange` does not emit for default values. That's how it behaves I guess. I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Did u get my answer ?

Comment: Thanks @selemmn, I got your answer. But I was wondering if there is any event similar to `selectionChange` which triggers for default value initialization. My code already knows how the default value is set, so I can do whatever I want to without using `ngAfterViewInit` as well. I appreciate your solution but it's not an answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a template ref (here : `#select`):

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select #select [(value)]="selectedSearchView"  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let view of searchViews; let i=index" [value]="view">
              {{view.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then in your Ts part, assuming you fill that default value as following:

```
constructor() {
    this.selectedSearchView = this.searchViews[0]
  }
```

You can proceed using `AfterViewInit` and `ViewChild` like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  selectedSearchView;
  searchViews = [
  {'name':'abc'},
  {'name':'def'},
  {'name':'ghi'}];

  @ViewChild('select') select;

  constructor() {
    this.selectedSearchView = this.searchViews[0]
  }

  onSelectionChange(event) {
    console.log('onSelectionChange called ! passed event :', event);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.select.value) {
      // here you can pass whatever you want as a parameter , I made an event-like object
      this.onSelectionChange({source:this.select, value: this.select.value});
    }
  }

}
```

[**Working demo.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgjxmc?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts)  (You'll have `Error: Object too large to inspect. Open your browser console to view.` so , open your browser console :) )